# POST API request in React js Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to POST my all form fields on API through Axios, but it is doesn't work and also did not show any error when I submit the form, so someone can please help me to solve this problem. I want to submit the form and all the records are store in API so when I access that API the new record should be shown. I did not understand where my logic is wrong.

```
import React from "react";

// reactstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  CardTitle,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  Input,
  Row,
  Col
} from "reactstrap";

import axios from 'axios';




class User extends React.Component {


  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col md="8">
              <Card className="card-user" style={{ width: '150%' }}>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h5">Edit Profile</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="5">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Company Name"
                            disabled
                            placeholder="Company"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="px-1" md="3">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Username</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="XYZ123"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">
                            Email address
                          </label>
                          <Input placeholder="Email" type="email" />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="6">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>First Name</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Abc"
                            placeholder="Company"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="6">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Last Name</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Pqr"
                            placeholder="Last Name"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Address</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="India"
                            placeholder="Home Address"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>City</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Pune"
                            placeholder="City"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="px-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Country</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Australia"
                            placeholder="Country"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Postal Code</label>
                          <Input placeholder="ZIP Code" type="number" />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>About Me</label>
                          <Input
                            type="textarea"
                            defaultValue=""
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <div className="update ml-auto mr-auto">
                        <Button
                          className="btn-round"
                          color="primary"
                          type="submit"
                        >
                          Update Profile
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Row>
                  </Form>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Did you check network tab in google chrome or in other browser, which you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to control your inputs via state since you are using a class-based component. Here's how you can do it. The `POST` request responds with a status of 201 here. Now that you have access to your form data, you could figure that out easily.

```
import React from "react";

// reactstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  CardTitle,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  Input,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "reactstrap";

import axios from "axios";

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    username: "",
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    postal: "",
    about: "",
  };

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state);
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = this.state;
    const response = await axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
      body: data,
    });
    console.log(response);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col md="8">
              <Card className="card-user" style={{ width: "150%" }}>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h5">Edit Profile</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="5">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Company Name"
                            disabled
                            placeholder="Company"
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="px-1" md="3">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Username</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="XYZ123"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">
                            Email address
                          </label>
                          <Input
                            placeholder="Email"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="6">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>First Name</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Abc"
                            placeholder="Company"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="6">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Last Name</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Pqr"
                            placeholder="Last Name"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Address</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="India"
                            placeholder="Home Address"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ address: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col className="pr-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>City</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Pune"
                            placeholder="City"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ city: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="px-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Country</label>
                          <Input
                            defaultValue="Australia"
                            placeholder="Country"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ country: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="pl-1" md="4">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>Postal Code</label>
                          <Input
                            placeholder="ZIP Code"
                            type="number"
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ postal: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <label>About Me</label>
                          <Input
                            type="textarea"
                            defaultValue=""
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              this.setState({ about: e.target.value })
                            }
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <div className="update ml-auto mr-auto">
                        <Button
                          className="btn-round"
                          color="primary"
                          type="submit"
                        >
                          Update Profile
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Row>
                  </Form>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help sir now it's working correctly